# Provide way for moderators to monitor specific users

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

As moderators, we occasionally need to deal with users who have needed intervention of some sort and don't warrant a suspension, but need to be monitored so we can follow up if they continue to cause problems. There is currently no way for us to automatically be informed of their activity. It would be nice if a "watch list" of sorts could be added to the moderator tools. We already have annotations, but this only allows us to see *who* has been moderated, not what they've done since.

One way this could be implemented is if under each user who has been recently annotated, you could click to expand and show their recent activity - last login, questions asked, edits/deletions, etc. This would would automatically make relevant info readily available for users who have already been annotated, making checking up on recent offenders a simple task. Alternatively, there could be a separate Watch List section on that page, with the same concept of clicking to expand a user's activity, but users would be specifically added to the watch list.

Based on conversations with other moderators and my own experience (for reference, I moderate on SU), I believe this would be a very useful feature for keeping tabs on borderline users.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76199/add-a-moderator-ability-to-watch-troublemakers

Comment: 10k mod tools section, "recent activity for users with flags" or something similar.

Comment: Noted, @Shog9. This request is a bit more detailed in terms of how it could be implemented, and with a slew of new moderators elected since that was posted, there's likely a greater usage case for this now. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: @Will is this an existing thing that I'm not seeing or a suggestion?

Comment: @nhinkle: A good idea for another section in the mod tools page.

Comment: If it is just a few offenders a moderator (or anyone else) could bookmark their activity pages.

Comment: @Martin in contravention to that let me suggest this: I routinely check my site as mod from my work computer and my personal laptop. I do _not_ connect the bookmarks between those two (kinda self-evident no?) so ... I would not like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have now implemented this as a User Script, available for download from Stack Apps for Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox:

> ## [Moderator Annotated User Recent Activity Watch List](https://stackapps.com/q/2434/5930)
>
> This script will add the ability to view the 10 most recent actions in any annotated user's timeline, exactly as it is displayed on their regular user profile. Just click the small arrow by a recently annotated user, and their recent activity will be displayed below. Click the arrow again to hide the timeline.
>
> [image: screenshot]

You can download the script from the Stack Apps page, or [directly from my webserver](http://files.nathanhinkle.com/download/se-mod-watchlist.user.js).

Comment: Live long, and prosper.