# Disadvantages of the new profile page for moderators

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, moderator-tools

The new profile page splits the information about a user into two pages, the Activity and the Profile page. The Activity page is generally more useful to moderators, which SE recognizes and made the default view for them even if they're looking at other users' profiles.

But the Activity page doesn't contain all the information that moderators need from the user profile. It is still sometimes necessary to look at the Profile page, and it is annoying that we have to look in two different places now to see information that was previously on the same page.

There's also information on the Activity page that I really don't care about when acting as a moderator. It doesn't matter to me how many badges the user has or what their next badge would be.

The information from the Profile page that is useful to moderators are mostly all the editable fields like the "About Me" or the user location and website. The age of the account is another piece of information that can be useful to know.

I suggest that the Activity view should be changed for moderators looking at the profiles of other users, or that the default view for mods is a third page based on the Activity page with additional information useful to moderators. The general idea would be to remove the reputation, badges and impact sections and replace them with something closer to the old header in user profiles. This would remove the need for moderators to switch between two pages of the user profile if they need access to that additional information.

Comment: Alternatively, a "mod profile view" page - a third page that consolidates everything that the mod cares about on one screen that is the default for moderators, yet still giving us access to the two public pages and not putting any mod-only information on those two pages? Really, I use information from both Profile and Activity when moderating, but all of the information on neither.

Comment: Specifically, I often find myself looking at last seen (profile), the links to other communities (profile / activity), answers (activity), questions (activity), and comments (activity, but need to drill down). Easy access to mod only information can be made more clear on a mod page, too, and remove the multiple clicks it currently takes (making it the old one-click-to-expose).

Comment: The nested tab navigation is pretty annoying even when you're no moderator.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I really like that idea. The "mod profile view" could also hold links for the actions/info stuff from the "mod" popup, too.

Comment: @ArthurFischer That would be the idea. Consolidate the information that is most relevant to moderators along with links to the mod tools related to a specific user, on one single page that is very clearly moderator-only. Then, let us have the other two pages available and leave them exactly how non-moderators see them. I have some ideas, but I can't give them here since they are about the mod-only tools.

Comment: What I miss most on "activity" as a mod (yet as a user, too) is "last seen." It even seems more natural under "activity."

Comment: I'm not a moderator anywhere, but I'd like to have this option as well (except for obvious stuff I'm not allowed to view). I don't like having to switch back and forth, would rather have activity be the default tab for me with all the things at top right , and about me section of profile tab put under activity tab for me. Thanks

Comment: "Last seen" is the one thing that I, as a moderator, keep having to switch views to get.  I think all my navigate-profiles-as-a-mod problems would be fixed if that and creation-date were reflected on the activity page.  (They're also useful for regular users in the profile view, but including them in both views is *just fine*.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio "Last seen" is available in the "Account info" box that you can toggle from any profile page. Account age could be included there, too.

Comment: @bfavaretto thanks!  I just noticed that a couple days ago too -- it sure is nice to be able to get it inline rather than having another page-load (and then having to navigate back because all the *other* stuff I want is on the activity page).

Answer (score 22):

I'm not opposed to a *support* tab in the profile page that is only visible to moderators and employees. This would basically contain any information that is relevant to moderating the site (in the scope of the current user), or assisting the user with whatever problem they're reporting to us.

For mods, this would be all of the information you'd want to see at a glance or be able to toggle, such as last seen, recent IP addresses, a rough overview of participation in the last 24 hours and some of the more interesting user history entries (e.g. they edited their profile) in the same period of time.

For us, this could contain network information, logs, login related stuff (that can quickly point out problems) and more. Of course, visible to employees that work on support (you wouldn't get any info you don't currently have, it would simply be easier to see and correlate).

Going to put a [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) as *something* like this should be coming out of a larger effort we've started to overhaul the tools in general, but it *might* materialize a little differently than I describe. We still need to hide any PII by default unless you click something to load it (and log access to it in the process).

Still, the main effort is 'save moderators clicks whenever possible' and this is a very good way of doing just that.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234071/162102

Answer (score 6):

There's now a "mod dashboard" tab of the profile that collects much of the most frequently accessed information that moderators need.

Comment: Is making the mod dashboard the default view for mods still considered? The dashboard is pretty nice, but it doesn't yet solve the issue that some information is one click further away than it used to be.