# Show me some activity

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

When I click on another user's profile the profile tab opens - always.

But in 99.9% of the time I want to see the activity tab. Can we save that extra click by remembering which tab I opened last on another user?

Or if most people feel the same - open the activity tab by default which is already been done on my own profile?

Comment: they seem to believe that when you click someone _else's_ user card, you want to see ["a view designed to give a better overall summary of who they are"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/249951/165773). Funny that this doesn't work for me (no, it's not what I usually want to see). Neither does it work for moderators: [Disadvantages of the new profile page for moderators](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260122/165773)

Comment: Client-side solution: ['Activity' tab on profile as default](http://stackapps.com/q/6267)

Answer (score 5):

I'm really torn about this.

I believe that it makes more sense to load up on the Profile tab. That's their front page, their calling card, their shop window. It's what we *should* see first.

Yet I can't help but agree that, in practice, I'm almost always on their profile in the first place to find out more about their activity. As such, this does get a bit annoying.

I suppose automatically storing an apparent preference as you suggest is the compromise here.

Comment: On other words: [branch prediction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902).

Comment: @1999: Haha I totally predicted somebody would link that

Comment: er, no pun intended