# Can we make it easier for moderators to notice chat flags when looking at a user's site profile?

Tags: feature-request, chat, flags, moderator-tools

A couple years ago SE implemented a [user dashboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234071/162102) for moderators, making it much easier to see at a glance a bunch of relevant information, including recent flags raised against the user.  This collective body of information helps us to decide when and how to contact users about patterns of behavior that we'd like them to change.

Recently I sent such a message and only later noticed that, in addition to the stuff I saw on that page, the user had been engaging in some problematic behavior in one of my site's chat rooms.  Had I noticed I *definitely* would have sent a stronger message, but sending a second one a day after the first saying "oh yeah, chat too!" doesn't feel right either.  Is there any way we can get some passive visibility into recent validated chat flags?

The dashboard already contains a link to the user's chat profile, so had I thought to go look I would have seen the flags there.  But I usually don't think to go look, and even if I do I have to click through a couple times and then look at dates to see if the flags were recent.

Chat integration is harder than reporting information on the main Q&A site, I know, but would it be possible to see something like "chat annotations: 3 last 7 days, 12 last 30 days" in that list of recent flags, with a link to the user's chat flags/annotations page?  An entry like that would tell moderators that there's something else to look at, without having to actually gather up those flags and report them individually like on-site flags are reported.  I'm also not asking that the counts be filtered per-site; chat flags don't have strong site associations, so there'd be (non-trivial) extra work in reporting only flags in this site's chat rooms.  And anyway, chat moderation is shared, so if I'm contacting a user about problematic comments on my site and notice that the user has been rude in chat -- but not on my own site -- I might still mention that.

Is there something helpful and not hard that we can do to make chat flags more visible on this dashboard?  I don't think a perma-link to the user's chat annotations would work; those could be from last week or six years ago.  Getting the information that there's *recent* stuff here onto the mod dashboard is an important part of the request.

Comment: Flags might be tricky; could probably do chat suspensions though.

Comment: @Shog9 thanks for pointing out an unintended vagueness.  I meant *validated* flags, not all flags.  Validated flags cause short suspensions, so that'd work.  (I had in mind the stuff that shows up on the chat profile for mods.)

Comment: I think calling them suspensions rather than validated flags makes more sense... I assume you'd also want to know about non-flag related suspensions? And, my guess is you probably want *both* the annotations and suspensions.

Comment: @Catija good point about wanting all suspensions, not just flag-caused ones. On the chat profile suspensions and annotations are listed together; that's the stuff I'd like to know about from the main site.

Comment: It shouldn't be difficult to have a "**Chat Problems**" link, clicking that opens a new Tab. On the new page would be a list of comments made in chat containing 'banned words' (flagged or not, along with the preceding and follow-up comments for context) - the truly curious could click on each box to visit the permalink. Boxes containing comments that were flagged and confirmed could be highlighted. I don't post this as an answer since I'm not a Mod and creating a mock-up of something I haven't seen/don't do is a bit much.

Comment: @Rob well, not new tabs because that's evil, but setting that aside: I think an important consideration is that "chat problems" (or whatever we call it) shows up if and only if there actually *are* chat problems.  Everything else in that section is "here's stuff people have flagged"; I'd like this to be similar.  If the link is always there we'll probably tune it out; if it shows up when there's something to see, we know to look.  If it links to the user's chat annotations, we can see the individual messages from there.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I tried to userscript this, but CORS and SE's aversion to iframes makes it difficult if not impossible :(