# Policy on potential troublemakers, nonconstructive or disruptive members?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, behavior, policy, vote-to-close

community. I searched on the background of troublemakers and found the following questions so far:

- [Add a moderator ability to watch troublemakers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76199/add-a-moderator-ability-to-watch-troublemakers)
- [What's the SO policy for swearing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79974/whats-the-so-policy-for-swearing)

*Bill the Lizard*, provides good points of how to **generally** proceed, yet in this case I am asking about a **specific** case.

In response to the swearing in the SO question below, I would like to ask for your opinion of how to handle such instances.  I am asking since stackoverflow is indexed within minutes by google, and definitely visited by young folk.[image]

Comment: Um. Flag. Flag. Also - flag.

Comment: In addition to what the others have said, please flag. ;)

Comment: Just to say - if you already know what to do in the general case, don't bring up specific cases. This only draws fire to the offenders, which is just not helping anyone.

Comment: Flag, vote to close and edit (removing the swears).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the SO policy for swearing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79974/whats-the-so-policy-for-swearing)

Comment: @ypercube Editing to remove the offensive text is good advice, but if you are going to edit then you _must_ use the custom flag and explicitly mention to the moderators that the evidence of the offense can (only) be found in the revision history. If, on the other hand, you are going to use the "it is not welcome in our community" flag, then it would be preferable to not edit out the offensive text.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As others have said in the comments, you should edit the post and remove the offensive text. Afterwards, flag the post for moderator attention. Be sure to use the "other" option so you can be sure to explain that the offensive part of the post has been removed and is in the revision history; otherwise, a moderator quickly trying to navigate through hundreds of flags may miss that there was a problem.

If you know how to link to revisions, you may want to include a link to the offensive revision in the "other" dialog when flagging. This helps the moderator more quickly catch up with what is happening.

While I normally encourage leaving comments whenever possible, even as a regular user, in situations like this, it may be best to let the moderators contact the user.

Comment: great answer. As you said constructive comments that reason with the user may aid as well. After all the user still has the benefit of the doubt: one is an incident, two is a coincidence and three is a pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Flag it for moderator attention and edit the post (if you have enough reputation). Vote the post down to tell future viewers that the post is bad and post it in chat so that more people can respond faster.

Comment: Downvoting isn't all about the downvotee's rep; it also signals that a post is bad for future viewers, and factors into the system's automatic cleanup algorithms.

Comment: @PopularDemand Fixed