# User Watch List For Mods

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, feed

As a moderator, we often have a set of users on our SE we need to be watching carefully, because they're clearly in the throes of misbehaving but either haven't crossed the line yet to get suspended or are just back from a suspension and may not have used the time to self-correct their behavior. So we informally go in and check their "all activity" views, but it'd be much more effective to have a "watch list" mod feature that we could use to view all activity on users we need to watch.

That's not just "faster," but it needs to include now-deleted content (we often have cases where the community power users rightly edit/delete out the malefactor's flipping out and cursing out another user, or they self-delete to try to cover up later, and there's actually no way for us to see that without going and viewing edit histories/deleted comments explicitly on a question - and how do we know to do that?).

This would be a short list of designated users that we'd get a rss-like feed of all activity, in its form at the time (not modified by later deletes/edits).

Ideally that would include chat too - since all mods share mod in chat, it's very often some off-site mod deletes bad stuff from one of our site users and we just plain never find out about it unless we get curious about some (deleted) in a recent chat-storm.

This is similar to the old request [Add a moderator ability to watch troublemakers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76199/add-a-moderator-ability-to-watch-troublemakers) but that one doesn't highlight the problem with seeing unedited/undeleted/chat content from these users.

Comment: Why?  In general they're the ones subjected to the terror from these bad actors, we mods can easily take care of ourselves.

Comment: Well terror watch list is usually known as a list of terrorists... users aren't going to go redo 9/11 here... so user watch list should a friendlier and more straightforward. Terror watch list seemed to be like a list of elite hackers or something the first time I read the title

Comment: Cough.. add... cough... a... cough... bounty... cough

Comment: Also, I assume the real name of the feature will be determined by SE UX people, as it should be.

Comment: I don't think this is fully a duplicate, as the requirement to see their unedited content isn't reflected there.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234071/162102 -- this info should be available for any user the mods decide to take a closer look at, not just ones who've previously been put on a watch list.

Comment: Definitely; half of the problem is not being able to really see all their activity. I think there's a third half (?) which is no place to audit all the recent flags and stuff - I'd kinda like to see all the recent flags, etc. even if they got handled by a user or another moderator or CommunityBot.

Comment: @mxyzplk I think the bit you have here that isn't part of that older request can be easily accomplished by just putting annotations on the user's profile.

Comment: I've been a moderator for some time now, and two of my diamonds are on particularly troublesome sites, each with more than a handful of trouble users. I've never felt the need for something as creepy as this. If RPG's trouble users are indeed that bad to justify us turning into Stasi, then just suspend their account for a year and move on.

Comment: @Keen you misunderstand the problem then. No mod finds out about it to make an annotation, the activity is done by "Community" or by power users and then all flags etc are cleaned up without a trace, unless you happen to go look in the exact spot.

Comment: @Yannis ridiculous analogies are unhelpful.  We can already see all of a user's activity and all, it's just not easy to see the deleted and undeleted all in one place. Please try to use logical reasons for/against and not random hyperbole, thanks.